# MSTest /noisolation fails tests

Tags: mstest

If I use MSTest with the parameter /noisolation my tests fail, but without it they pass.
If I run MSTest without the parameter for the first time a ms office configuration box appears and configures something because my tests depend on excel. this happens only the first time. then the test runs trough without problems.

but if I run my test with the parameter the box doesn't appear and tests fail.

Comment: I am not sure what the reason but as per MSDN - Run tests within the MSTest.exe process. This choice improves test run speed but increases risk to the MSTest.exe process.